# Lighthouse returned error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST

Tags: google-pagespeed

My website uses `prestashop 1.7`.
I have a problem with the google page speed tool.

I

> `Lighthouse returned error: ERRORED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. 
>   Lighthouse did not manage to completely load the requested page. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and the server is responding correctly to all requests. (Status code: 403)`

Comment: care to share your URL so I can look at it for you.

Comment: Just so you are aware the error code is most likely to indicate that you are trying to send Google to a page it cannot access (hence the 403: forbidden error code), but want to check that for you

Answer (score -2):

Ligthouse has run into issues lately, we were having same issues time and again, even the result scores does not seem accurate anymore.